# How to include mixins in a loop and fetch data in pug

Tags: html, for-loop, foreach, pug, mixins

I have following mixins which contains `svg` files.

```
mixin gift_icon
   svg ..

mixin leat_icon
   svg ..

mixin pyramid_icon
   svg ..
```

In my `index.pug` file. I'm trying fetch above `mixins` via loop.

```
    .grid-container
        - 
            grid_items = [
                {icon: +leaf_icon, title: "Title 01"},
                {icon: +gift_icon, title: "Title 02"},
            ]

        each item in grid_items
            .grid
                figure
                    item.icon
                a(href="")= item.title
```

But the `mixin` part is not fetching correctly. It just creating a `class`.

[image: output]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't store the `mixin` result in a javascript variable. A workaround could be to store the mixins in an javascript object.

```
- 
  var mixins = {
    gift_icon: '<span>svg</span>',
    leat_icon: '<span>svg</span>',
    pyramid_icon: '<span>svg</span>',
  }

.grid-container
  - 
    grid_items = [
      {icon: mixins.gift_icon, title: "Title 01"},
      {icon: mixins.leat_icon, title: "Title 02"},
      {icon: mixins.pyramid_icon, title: "Title 03"},
    ]

each item in grid_items
  .grid
    figure !{item.icon}
  a(href="")= item.title
```

By the way: to get the variables output as escaped html use `figure !{item.icon}`.